# Closing a HTTP connection after data is received

Tags: php, http

I am sending and receiving data using fsockopen and fwrite. My application receives the proper response, but seems to wait until some sort of timeout before continuing. I suspect that I am not closing the connection properly after it finishes receiving the response, which explains the wait. Could someone take a look at my code?

```
private static function Send($URL, $Data) {
            $server = parse_url($URL, PHP_URL_HOST);
            $port = parse_url($URL, PHP_URL_PORT);

            // If the parsing the port information fails, we will assume it's on a default port.
            // As such, we'll set the port in the switch below.
            if($port == null) {
                switch(parse_url($URL, PHP_URL_SCHEME)) {
                    case "HTTP":
                        $port = 80;
                        break;
                    case "HTTPS":
                        $port = 443;
                        break;

                }
            }

            // Check if we are using a proxy (debug configuration typically).
            if(\HTTP\HTTPRequests::ProxyEnabled) {
                $server = \HTTP\HTTPRequests::ProxyServer;
                $port = \HTTP\HTTPRequests::ProxyPort;
            }

            // Open a connection to the server.
            $connection = fsockopen($server, $port, $errno, $errstr);
            if (!$connection) {
                die("OMG Ponies!");
            }

            fwrite($connection, $Data);

            $response = "";
            while (!feof($connection)) {
                $response .= fgets($connection);
            }
            fclose($connection);

            return $response;
        }
```

Comment: Did you try toying with the `timeout` value? http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but look at the note at the top of http://php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php under the heading "Warning: If a connection opened by fsockopen() wasn't closed by the server, feof() will hang. To workaround this, see below example"

Comment: @BenLee Hmm. The modification does not appear to be working. Still taking like 30 seconds to timeout.

Comment: @user978122, yeah looking at the code I can't figure out how it could possibly help. Just saw it in the docs though, and figured I post it in case I was missing something. Guess not :/

Comment: @BenLee Do you think it would be possible to strip out the content length from the stream, and close the connection after receiving the nth byte?

Comment: @user978122, if you know *exactly* how long the content you will be receiving is (in bytes) you can read in just that many and not even check for an EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
while (!feof($connection)) {
```

Sockets are streams; unless the other side closes the connection *first*, `feof` will never return `true` and your script will eventually time out.

To perform an orderly shutdown both parties have to close their end of the connection; *one* of them can do it as a response to the other, but clearly if both are waiting for the other to close first then noone ever will.

Does the program on the other side close the connection after outputting something? It seems not.

Comment: I now parse the header to get the content length, and use that to determine when to severe the connection.

Comment: @user978122: That's a good way if you can pull it off (meaning, if the server does send the content length). Cheers!